# How to arrange Facebook Graph API respond

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, response

When I execute a get from Facebook graph I got a comlex string.

Is there a method for breaking it into "Graph Users"?

For example:

```
{"data":[{"id":"112221111"},{"id":"112221111"},{"id":"112221111"},{"score":{"data":[{"score":77777,"user":{"id":"5551","name":"כr"},"application":{"id":"3463464363636336","namespace":"tomatosmasher","name":"Tomato Smasher"}]},"id":"667677577575","installed":true},{"id":"55555555"},{"id":"55555555"},{"id":"55555555"},{"id":"55555555"},{"id":"55555555"},{"id":"55555555"},{"id":"55555555"},{"id":"55555555"},
```

The code I'm using

```
                String currentUserFBID = user.getId();
                String currentUserAccessToken = Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken();

// Execute the HTTP Get to our server for the scores of the user's friends
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String getURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + currentUserFBID + "/friends?access_token=" + currentUserAccessToken + "&fields=installed,score";
                HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
                HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);

// Parse the response
                HttpEntity responseEntity = responseGet.getEntity();
                String response = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's not a "complex" String, it's JSON. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , dmon is correct

I was needed to convert in to JSON

And handle it by this tutorial.

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/